# What is the most easy way to install gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to uninstall a gem "rubyzip 1.1.0" and install the older version "rubyzip 0.9.9"

I need to enter in a specific folder in ssh to do this?

I need upload some file to sftp or I can do a command with some url?

If there is a very simple way even I am very grateful.

Comment: Is this as for a project which has a file called `Gemfile`? That would make things different (easier usually).

Comment: I have an application in ruby where I need to uninstall a gem and install another only that.

Comment: i dont know how to do this.

Comment: Does the application have a file called `Gemfile` in its root folder? It really should . . . although if it doesn't your problem *can* be fixed easily using global gems (not ideal because that might break something else that wants the later version of `rubyzip`)

Comment: i have this "/home/webserver/.gems/gems" Neil Slater.

And this too "/home/webserver/.gems/gems/rubyzip-0.9.9"

Comment: You can put step by step how to do this?

Comment: I cannot add a step-by-step, because I do not understand the setup from your description. Where is the application installed? Look in *that* folder. Do you see a file called `Gemfile`?

Comment: Here have gemfile "/home/webserver/app"

Comment: OK, edit that file and make sure it has the right version for `rubyzip`. Take a look at http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile.html for a quick reference. You will need to run `bundle install` (in the same folder) after your edit

Comment: ok. 1 - find a file called "gemfile". 2 - Edit the file and put the version of a gem i want, like "gem rubyzip" to "gem rubyzip 0.9.9". 3 - enter in folder(using ssh) where i find a file called "gemfile". 4 - run "bundle install". this is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take a look at your `Gemfile` and look for the line `gem 'rubyzip'`.
2. Change this line to: `gem 'rubyzip', '0.9.9'`
3. Now run `bundle install` from your application root directory to fetch and install the downgraded gem (and all of its dependencies).
4. Done.

Comment: You can put step by step to do this brother?

Comment: Chopped answer into steps as you asked. If you are still finding this hard to grasp then read some more about `gems` and the `bundler` command.